# Replace this persistent entity with a simple POJO or DTO object?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

i ve been using sonar to test my code quality but i cant resolve the vulnerability issue with my code it said that i should use Dto or pojo class instead of entity class but sill cant resolve it i dont know how to convert my entity to dto class.
here is my entiy class:

```
@Entity
public class Mission implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -5369734855993305723L;


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

private String name;

private String description;

@ManyToOne
private Departement departement;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="mission")
private  List<Timesheet> timesheets;

public Mission() {
    super();
}

public Mission(String name, String description){
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
}


public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public Departement getDepartement() {
    return departement;
}

public void setDepartement(Departement departement) {
    this.departement = departement;
}

public List<Timesheet> getTimesheets() {
    return timesheets;
}

public void setTimesheets(List<Timesheet> timesheets) {
    this.timesheets = timesheets;
}
```

and here is the Restcontroller method where i got the isssue:

```
    @PostMapping("/ajouterMission")
@ResponseBody
public int ajouterMission(@RequestBody Mission mission) {
    itimesheetservice.ajouterMission(mission);
    try {
        logger.info("in ajouter Mission");
        logger.debug("Je vais commencer l'ajout");
        itimesheetservice.ajouterMission(mission);
        logger.info("out ajouter Mission");
        return mission.getId();
        }
    catch (Exception e) { logger.error("Erreur dans ajouterMission() : " , e); }
    return mission.getId();
}
```

and this is a screenshot about the sonar vulnerability issue for more details :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reRuM.png)

Comment: What exact problem are you having creating a DTO?

Comment: i have created DTO But sonar still seeing it as an entity if u have any suggestion how to convert my entity to DTO class and how to use it on controller

Comment: [this is the rule description](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/spring/RSPEC-4684), please see the "compliant solution" section..., to accomplish this on a "bigger project": https://www.google.com/search?q=java+mapping+framework+comparison

Comment: your `@Post/Get/.../RequestMapping` still has arguments, which (classes) are annotated `@Entity`, what the rule is actually complaining about. ..a DTO is a class, which looks [somewhat - very] like the entity ..and has a similar name, but the controllers and services have to transform them (back&forth)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DO NOT put your Entity model into Controller method. You must create another model like `MissionRequestModel` for `@RequestBody`, and then convert your request model to your entity

```java
public class MissionRequestModel {
private String name;
private String description;
}
```

```java
@PostMapping("/ajouterMission")
@ResponseBody
public int ajouterMission(@RequestBody MissionRequestModel missionRequestModel) {
     Mission mission = new Mission(missionRequestModel);
}
```

Comment: thanks i just had to set a new constructor on mission entity that convert MissionDTO to a mission and called it on the controller